# iOS app lifecycle regarding CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion

Tags: objective-c, geolocation, cllocationmanager, lifecycle

In iOS one can purportedly use the `CLLocationManager`'s `startMonitoringForRegion:` method to register a delegate to respond to the device moving into a specific geographic region, even when the app isn't launched.  From the [CLLocationManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> In iOS, the regions you register with the location manager persist between launches of your application. If a region crossing occurs while your iOS app is not running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in the background so that it can process the event. When relaunched, all of the regions you configured previously are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location manager objects you create.

I assume if the app is relaunched, iOS doesn't actually bring it to the foreground.  I couldn't find any good samples illustrating where `startMonitoringForRegion` fits into an overall application, so my questions are:

1. Does one have to register the delegate for `startMonitoringForRegion` from somewhere specific?  I'm guessing it can't be plonked in a view controller if we're launching the app without bringing it into the foreground.  Can someone give an example with some context around it?
2. If we decide we *do* want to bring the app into the foreground as a result of entering the region, how would we do so?
3. When is `startMonitoringForRegion` registered with the OS and when is it unregistered?  Does the user have to have launched the app at least once (even if it's since been killed) for the initial registration to take place?  What about if the user powers off the device?  Will our handler be registered the next time the device is powered on, or will the user have to launch the app at least once again?

Comment: What the class reference mean is that the application will be relaunched and in the applicationDidFinishLaunching:option, the options will contain key 'UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey' to indicate the app is relaunched due to detected didEnterRegion/didExitRegion monitored regions. If the key is detected, you will need to reinit the location manager and the delegates before you can do any handling inside the delegates.

Answer (score 1):

> Does one have to register the delegate for startMonitoringForRegion from somewhere specific? I'm guessing it can't be plonked in a view controller if we're launching the app without bringing it into the foreground.

False. A view controller object still **does** exists if it's allocated-initialized, even if its contents are not presented.

> If we decide we do want to bring the app into the foreground as a result of entering the region, how would we do so?

Not possible using public APIs (I'm not sure whether an app in the background can use `- [UIApplication openURL:]` with its own URL scheme to  bring itself into the background, but I doubt it); however you may be able to use the SpringBoardServices framework to launch your app:

```
SBSLaunchApplicationWithIdentifier(CFSTR("com.mycompany.theBestiPhoneAppEver"), false);
```

> When is startMonitoringForRegion registered with the OS and when is it unregistered? Does the user have to have launched the app at least once (even if it's since been killed) for the initial registration to take place?

If the user never runs your application, code inside will never be run, so it won't get registered.

> What about if the user powers off the device? Will our handler be registered the next time the device is powered on, or will the user have to launch the app at least once again?

Now that's a good question. I don't know it off the top of my head, nor did I find an answer in the documentation (probably you haven't found that either), so I'd say you just better try it yourself to be sure.